# Why does Github Flavored Markup only add newlines for lines that start with [\w\<]?

Tags: github, newline, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

In our site (which is aimed at **highly** non-technical people), we let them use Markdown when sending emails. That way, they get nice things like bold, italic, etc. Being non-technical, however, they would never get past the “add two lines to make newlines actually work” quirk.

For that reason mainly, we are using a variant of [Github Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/).

We mainly borrowed this part:

```ruby
# in very clear cases, let newlines become <br /> tags
text.gsub!(/^[\w\<][^\n]*\n+/) do |x|
   x =~ /\n{2}/ ? x : (x.strip!; x << "  \n")
end
```

This works well, but in some cases it doesn’t add the new-lines, and I guess the key to that is the “in very clear cases” part of that comment.

If I interpret it correctly, this is only adding newlines for lines that start with either a word character or a ‘<’.

Does anyone know why that is? Particularly, why ‘<’?

What would be the harm in just adding the two spaces to essentially anything (lines starting with spaces, hyphens, anything)?

Answer (score 1):

'<' character is used at the beginning of a line to quote messages. I guess that is the reason.

Comment: I think '>' is more often used for quoting.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer to this question is quite wrong.  This has nothing to do with quoting, and the character for markdown quoting is `>`.

```
 ^[\w\<][^\n]*\n+
```

Let's break the above regex into parts:

- `^` = anchor start of string.
- `[\w\<]` matches a word character or the start of word boundary.  `\<` is ***not*** a literal, but rather a GNU word boundary.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) (do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for `\<`).
- `[^\n]*` matches any length of non-newline characters
- `\n` matches a new line.
- `+` is, I believe, a possessive quantifier.

I believe, but am not 100% sure, that this simply is used to set `x` to a line of text.  Then, the heavy work is done with the next line:

```
x =~ /\n{2}/ ? x : (x.strip!; x << "  \n")
```

This says "if `x` satisfies the regex `\n{2}` (that is, has two line breaks), leave `x` as is.  Otherwise, strip `x` and append a newline character.

Comment: `+` means one or more of whatever's before the `+`: `c+` is `c` or `cc` or `ccc` ... for any single character `c`; `\n+` is "one or more newlines" -- the `\n` is a single character; `(bla)+` is "bla" or "blabla" ...